# Google Script Editor: getLastRow values and paste (values only) into penultimate row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried 10+ variations of the following script to try and achieve what I thought would be a simple function to copy the values in the last row of my Google Sheet and paste them into the penultimate row. The last and penultimate rows that contain data will always be changing so I cannot specify a static range for either. Here are the 2 closest versions I've written:

```
function Export() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
var source = ss.getSheetByName('aaa');
var last_row = source.getLastRow();
var second_last_row = (last_row-1);
var copyData = source.getRange(second_last_row).setValues(last_row);
}
```

The error here is "Range not found" for the 'var CopyData' line. If I re-write this line as follows:
var copyData = source.getRange.second_last_row.setValues(last_row);
I get an error that says "cannot read property 'setValues' of undefined".

I have tried this version as well:

```
function copyv() {
 var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
 var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("aaa");
 var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
 let source = last_row
 let destination = last_row-1
      source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

And in this sample I get the error that "source.copyTo is not a function" although this works in other functions I've written where the range is static (ex: A5:BC, not "last_row").

Any and all help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grab values not just the row:

```
function Export() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
var source = ss.getSheetByName('aaa');

var last_row = source.getLastRow();
var last_column = source.getLastColumn();
var data = source.getRange(last_row,1,1,last_column).getValues();//gets actual data
var destination_range = source.getRange(last_row-1,1,1,last_column);//creates target range
source.getRange(data).setValues(destination_range);
}
```

In your version you were trying to copy an integer to an integer rather than an  array to a range.